# Building a histogram

Tags: pandas

How can a distribution histogram similar to this one be constructed based on the data from the table?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbuPW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Fu0.png)

Code python:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')
print(df)
df.plot.hist(df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear exactly what the `x` and `y` axes of your desired plot are. Hopefully this will get you started. Sometimes trying to comeup with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you solve your own problem.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#######################################
# generate some random data for a MWE #
#######################################
random.seed(22)
data = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(0, 10)]
data = pd.Series(sorted(data))

freqs = [random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(0, 10)]
freqs = sorted(freqs)
freqs = pd.Series(freqs)


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['data'] = data
df['frequencies'] = freqs

###############################################
# Desired bar plot using pandas built in plot #
###############################################
df.plot(x='data', y='frequencies', kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Cousin Dupree, x- data, y-frequencies

Comment: Cousin Dupree, the problem is that the hist histogram does not give the desired result, as in the screenshot.